# Change label color dynamically in Ionic2

Tags: ionic2

I have a string property with values like "primary", "secondary" or "danger". I am able to bind it to a badge in this way:

```
<ion-badge class="badge badge-{{product.colorStock}}">1</ion-badge>
```

But I am not able to do the same with a label (this does NOT work):

```
<ion-label class="label label-{{product.colorStock}}">Text</ion-label>
```

How could I bind my property to the label so it changes its color?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe is it doable with [ngClass] directive ?

Comment: If you mean <ion-label [ngClass]="{{product.colorStock}}">Text</ion-label>, it does not work. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved by Ionic2 Framework itself, introducing the "color" tag. Now label sintax is:

```
<ion-label color="danger">Text</ion-label>
```

So, the problem does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
<ion-label class="label" [ngClass]="['label-'+product.colorStock]">Text</ion-label>
```

Comment: It compiles to <ion-label class="label label-secondary">Text</ion-label>, and so it does not show in green. I am looking for something that compiles to <ion-label secondary">Text</ion-label>. Thank you